# Temporarily Unavailable GENERIC_HTTP_503

Tags: rest, http, jetty

i have an application that runs through VM and performing multiple activities on it sometimes displays "Temporarily unavailable" message.
i have seen the debug logs and jetty server logs and it displays GENERIC_HTTP_503 error but for a rest call which is not known.
is there any way to know why exactly this problem is occurring inconsistently?
and is this because of server is overloaded with multiple requests?